# Why does this come up when I open terminal: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'?

Tags: bash

Apologies if this is not the appropriate community to post this. Feel free to link me to the appropriate stackexchange community where my questions applies. I have searched about this error on the site, but since I'm not tech-savvy I don't understand what is going on so thank you for bearing with me.

Problem: Whenever I start the terminal on my mac I obtain this error

```
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: `    fi'
```

I'm not sure what this means and what is going on. I don't even understand what bash means. Would someone be able to explain to me what is going on?

I noticed the problem when I was trying to install MySQL from this video (time stamp: 1:09:04): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY&t=3950s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

It's supposed to look like this:
[image]

However this is what it looks like for me:

```
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: `    fi'
Anthonys-Air:~ -bash: /Users/Anthonywes$ echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
Anthonys-Air:~ -bash: /Users/Anthonywes$ . ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /Users/Anthonywes/.bash_profile: line 12: `    fi'
```

Here is the content of .bash_profile below:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/Anthonywes/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/Anthonywes/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/Anthonywes/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

I do remember a couple of months ago that I tried to uninstall Anaconda and it said to delete a line in that file. Is that where the error is coming from?

**Questions:**
So my question is two-fold:

1. What do the errors on the first 2 lines pertaining to `fi' actually mean? I want to understand generally what is going on.
2. How do I fix it, and can you explain why what you wrote fixes it?

Comment: Is what you posted the actual content of your .bash_profile?

Comment: Sorry I removed the muck up with the copy and paste in the previous one where I had an additional "-bash: /Users/ ". Does that make sense now?

Comment: Don't really understand what you're telling me. Could you add the actual content of the .bash_profile file to your question?

Comment: The thing is I don't even know what file you're referring to? Where can I find the content of the .bash_profile? I don't know really know anything about using the terminal since I'm just trying to install MySQL. I don't even know what you mean by the content of the .bash_profile. I'm just copy and pasting what I see on the terminal.

Comment: You will find a file .bash_profile in your home directory. I mean, the path is even shown in your console except. And: I'm afraid a slightly tighter grip on console usage might be desirable before you start working with databases.

Comment: Okay I found it. Thank you very much! I do remember deleting a line in that file a few months ago in the else part of __conda_setup. But I obviously do not know what I'm doing and just following instructions as per the uninstallation guide for Anaconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Answer (score 4):

It's a syntax error to have an empty branch in an `if` statement:

```bash
else
(nothing)        
fi
```

This leads to your error. Remove the remove the empty `else` branch:

```bash
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/Anthonywes/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/Anthonywes/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    fi
fi
```

More info at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Removing the ```else``` branch removes the error upon opening the terminal, but is it not undesirable practice to not have an ```else``` branch? 

I realised the issue was from another time when I followed instructions to uninstall Anaconda (see here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and it asked to remove a line in the else section (but not the ```else``` statement itself).

Comment: @tcmtan No, it is only unneeded in this scenario. Nothing with best practices.